# jquery Hover problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, hoverintent

Consider my HTML

```
<div class="abu">
<div id="pfabricsmenu1" class="box_conti_homepage">
<h2 class="tel_title"><a rel="dropmenu1" href="/new_site/?page_id=127">Telecommunications</a><br />
<img title="Telecommunications" src="wp-content/uploads/2011/03/box_image.jpg" alt="Telecommunications" width="191" height="76" />
</h2>

<div id="dropmenu1" class="box_text_homepage">
<ul>
    <li><a href="/new_site/?page_id=174">Business Telephone Systems</a></li>
    <li><a href="/new_site/?page_id=66">Hosted IP Telephony</a></li>
    <li><a href="/new_site/?page_id=67">Fixed Line Telecoms Management</a></li>
    <li><a href="/new_site/?page_id=83">Mobile Telecoms Management</a></li>
    <li><a href="/new_site/?page_id=85">Inbound Call management</a></li>
    <li><a href="/new_site/?page_id=70">Telephone Support Services</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="mou">Getting the best from your telecoms with the latest technology to suit your business.</div>
</div>
```

I would like to do hover on `<h2>` such that `div.box_text_homepage` slides down when the mouse is over it and slides up when the mouse is hovered out. My problem is that the menu slides back up even when the mouse is over `div.box_text_homepage`, how do I stop that?

```
       $('.box_title_bar_homepage .abu').each(function(){

        var $maindiv = this;

        $(this).find('h2').hoverIntent(function(){
            $($maindiv).find('.box_text_homepage').slideDown();
        },function(){
            $($maindiv).find('.box_text_homepage').slideUp();
        })

   })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    $('.box_text_homepage').hover(function(){
        $(this).slideDown();
    },function(){
        $(this).slideUp();
    })
```

Comment: `.box_text_homepage` is set to display: none

Comment: lol well thats silly, than how do u expect a user to hover it?

Comment: I don't get it. You want hover-functionality on a hidden element?

Comment: @neal posted at the same time :)

Comment: @Justus and the double post adds emphasis :-)

Comment: pardon me I forgot to code `<h2>` in the question, I want that hover on `<h2>`. Does that make sense?

Comment: your questions says you are hovering over `box_text_homepage`

Comment: lol :) Sorry for all this confusion, When I move my mouse over on <h2>,  `.box_text_homepage` should slide down, it should not slide back up when the mouse is over `.box_text_homepage` after it has slid down.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this:

```
$("#dropmenu1").hover(function(){
        $(this).children().slideDown();
    },function(){
        $(this).children().slideUp();
});
```